# Openlayers4 ol.layer.Group only gets first item

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to change the opacity of vector layers using one slider but I seem not to get the right logic to loop each item as opposed to just the first. Here is my code so far. [Link to full code](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0oSbfFDK1Q6tCbMoWxu?p=preview)

This is where I guess I have the particular issue.

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, i) {
      bindInputs('#layer' + i, layer);
      if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
        layer.getLayers().forEach(function(sublayer, j) {
          bindInputs('#layer' + (i) + (j), sublayer);
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it's an OpenLayers problem.  Adding `console.log('#layer' + (i) + (j));` to your code shows it is getting all the layers.  For some reason I don't understand the binding is only working on one vector layer.  The code should also work on the OSM layer, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, @Mike. It doesn't look like an ol issue but had to include it in the title just to get to the appropriate audience (despite the tag). That said, in the link I provided, just the first layer works on moving the range bar.

Comment: Just discovered my error.

It works this way now.

`<div id="layer1">
            <input class="transp" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>
          </div>`

and changed this too

`bindInputs('#layer' + (j), sublayer);`

[link updated with solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0oSbfFDK1Q6tCbMoWxu?p=preview)